# Linux kernel: ioremap and copy_from_user is terribly slow

Tags: linux, memory, kernel, mapping

Writing a driver that gets a physical memory address and a buffer size from the BIOS. That area is e.g. 32 MB in size.

The drivers job is now to fill this buffer with data which comes from a userspace buffer.

So the current approach is:

```
virt_addr=ioremap(physical_addr, buffersize);
copy_from_user(virt_addr, userspace_addr, buffersize);
```

This approach works, but it is terribly slow. There's another approach in which I use memeory allocated with kmalloc and if I do a

```
copy_from_user(kmalloc_allocated_buffer, userspace_addr, buffersize);
```

It seems to be at least 10 times faster to copy the buffer than the approach with ioremap. So I assume I'm doing it wrong, but how can I do it right?

Even tried ioremeap_wt to have a writethrough cached region, but this does not accelerate the copying at all.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *"gets a physical memory address and a buffer size from the BIOS"*?  There is no interaction between the Linux kernel and the PC BIOS.  FYI since the memory is to be used for I/O, the mapping by **ioremap()** will typically be marked uncachable, which could explain the perceived slowness.  You are also misusing the address returned by **ioremap()**.  Study https://lwn.net/Articles/653585/

Comment: BIOS has impelemented an interface  for a vendor specific ACPI node. I have a method to query the BIOS for that buffer and I get the physical address and size back. Querying means in that case means doing an SMI call.